# Lighttpd stop responding to php calls

Tags: php, lighttpd, gentoo, mod-fastcgi

I am running 2 servers with Lighttpd 1.4.45 with fastcgi and php 5.6 on gentoo linux.

We have a problem in both servers that about twice a day the Lighttpd stop responding to php calls, only restart of Lighttpd makes it operational again.

There is nothing in the error.log.

What we do see.

1. There are several **503 responses** prior to the event where the lighttps stopped responding to php calls.
2. There are a list of old fastcgi in /var/run/lighttpd/

   - srwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd lighttpd 0 Aug 27 10:45 lighttpd-fastcgi-php-3673.socket-4
   - srwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd lighttpd 0 Aug 27 10:45 lighttpd-fastcgi-php-3673.socket-5
   - srwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd lighttpd 0 Oct  3 06:49 lighttpd-fastcgi-php-6038.socket-0
   - srwxr-xr-x 1 lighttpd lighttpd 0 Oct  3 06:49 lighttpd-fastcgi-php-6038.socket-1

What could be the issue?

Comment: Does the problem occur at a consistent time of day (every day, same time)?

Comment: No, it could happen at any moment of the day

Comment: It happened to me every day between one and 4 times

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is fixed since lighttpd 1.4.50.  The latest lighttpd release is lighttpd 1.4.51.